# Using one iron-ajax element for multiple requests

Tags: polymer

Theoretically, it should be possible to use one `iron-ajax` element for multiple requests by setting the `auto` attribute and then repeatedly setting the `url` property on the element. `iron-ajax` has a property called `activeRequests`, which is a read-only array, so it seems like it has supports for queueing up multiple requests simultaneously. However in practice it does not appear to work.

For example, in the JS Bin below, I retrieve a list of book IDs for books that contain the word `polymer`, and then use a `for` loop to repeatedly set the value of `url`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="single iron-ajax for multiple requests">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script href="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax id="ajax"
                 url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=polymer"
                 handle-as="json"
                 on-response="onResponse"
                 last-response="{{response}}" auto></iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-el',
        properties: {
          response: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true
          }
        },
        onResponse: function(e) {
          var ajax = this.$.ajax;
          var originalUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=polymer';
          var url = ajax.lastRequest.xhr.responseURL;
          if (url.includes(originalUrl)) {
            console.log('this is the first request');
            for (var i = 0; i < ajax.lastResponse.items.length; i++) {
              ajax.url = this.url(ajax.lastResponse.items[i].id);
            }            
          } else {
            console.log(ajax.lastResponse.selfLink);
          }
        },
        url: function(id) {
          return "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/" + id;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <my-el></my-el>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's indeed possible to use `iron-ajax` for multiple requests but not with `auto` enabled, or else you'll hit `iron-ajax`'s [debouncer](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/bcdb5d3/iron-ajax.html#L496). From the Polymer [docs for `iron-ajax`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax):

> With `auto` set to `true`, the element performs a request whenever its `url`, `params` or `body` properties are changed. Automatically generated requests will be debounced in the case that multiple attributes are changed sequentially.

In your question's code:

```
// template
<iron-ajax auto ...>

// script
onResponse: function(e) {
  ...
  for (var i = 0; i < ajax.lastResponse.items.length; i++) {
    ajax.url = this.url(ajax.lastResponse.items[i].id);
  }
}
```

...you're presumably expecting `iron-ajax` to generate a new request with each URL, but the [debouncer collapses the requests into one](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/6c5afe5/src/mini/debouncer.html#L22-L32) (taking only the last invocation).

Also worth noting: The `response` handler's event detail (i.e., `e.detail`) is the corresponding `iron-request`, which contains the AJAX response (i.e., `e.detail.response`). Using the event detail is preferrable because it avoids a race condition in simultaneous requests from `iron-ajax`, where `this.$.ajax.lastResponse` or `this.$.ajax.lastRequest` are overwritten asynchronously.

```
onResponse: function(e) {
  var request = e.detail;
  var response = request.response;
}
```

To reuse `iron-ajax` with a new URL, disable `auto` (which disables the debouncer) and manually call `generateRequest()` after updating the URL. This would allow multiple simultaneous async requests (and `activeRequests` would populate with more than one request).

```
// template
<iron-ajax ...>   <!-- no 'auto' -->

// script
onResponse: function(e) {
  var request = e.detail;
  var response = request.response;
  ...
  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    ajax.url = this.url(response.items[i].id);
    ajax.generateRequest();
  }
},
ready: function() {
  this.$.ajax.generateRequest(); // first request
}
```

Here's a modified version of your code:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <!-- We're reusing this iron-ajax to fetch more data
         based on the first response, and we don't want
         iron-ajax's debouncer to limit our requests,
         so disable 'auto' (i.e., remove the attribute
         from <iron-ajax>). We'll call generateRequest()
         manually instead.
      -->
    <iron-ajax id="ajax"
               url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=polymer"
               handle-as="json"
               on-response="onResponse"
               on-error="onError">
      </iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          onError: function(e) {
            console.warn('iron-ajax error:', e.detail.error.message, 'url:', e.detail.request.url);
          },
          onResponse: function(e) {
            var ajax = this.$.ajax;
            var originalUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=polymer';
            var url = e.detail.url;
            if (url.includes(originalUrl)) {
              var books = e.detail.response.items || [];
              console.log('this is the first request');
              for (var i = 0; i < books.length && i < 3; i++) {
                ajax.url = this.url(books[i].id);
                console.log('fetching:', ajax.url);
                ajax.generateRequest();
              }
            } else {
              var book = e.detail.response;
              console.log('received:', e.detail.url, '"' + book.volumeInfo.title + '"');
            }
          },
          url: function(id) {
            return "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/" + id;
          },
          ready: function() {
            // generate first request
            this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

https://jsbin.com/qaleda/edit?html,console

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's up with the `activeRequests` property, but I was able to get it to work by re-structuring my code a little. Basically, just implement a queue, and pop off an item from the queue and set `url` once the last request has finished.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817472">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script href="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax id="ajax"
                 url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=polymer"
                 handle-as="json"
                 on-response="onResponse"
                 last-response="{{response}}" auto></iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-el',
        properties: {
          response: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true
          },
          queue: {
            type: Array,
            notify: true,
            value: function() { return []; }
          }
        },
        onResponse: function(e) {
          var ajax = this.$.ajax;
          var originalUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=polymer';
          var url = ajax.lastRequest.xhr.responseURL;
          if (url.includes(originalUrl)) {
            console.log('this is the first request');
            for (var i = 0; i < ajax.lastResponse.items.length; i++) {
              this.push('queue', ajax.lastResponse.items[i].id);
            }
            ajax.url = this.url(this.pop('queue'));
          } else {
            console.log(ajax.lastResponse.selfLink);
            ajax.url = this.url(this.pop('queue'));
          }
        },
        url: function(id) {
          return "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/" + id;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <my-el></my-el>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/beyawe/edit?html,console

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [iron-multiple-ajax-behavior](https://github.com/ankitsorathiya/iron-multiple-ajax-behavior).
Let me know if this can be useful to you.